# Failed selection on union range

Tags: excel, vba

I try to select the range that was union under one variable, but it fails.

```
Sub filter()
    'Clear prev result table
    Worksheets("main").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Delete

    'Declare variable
    Dim selectedRows As Range
    Set selectedRows = Worksheets("contacts").Range("A1:B1")


    'Get total used range in contacts database
    numRows = Mid(Worksheets("contacts").UsedRange.Address, 9)
    For Each cell In Worksheets("contacts").Range("B1:B" & numRows)
        If cell.Value = Worksheets("main").Range("B1").Value Then
            'If true, push into array called selectedRows
            Set selectedRows = Application.Union(selectedRows, Worksheets("contacts").Range(cell.Address))
        End If
    Next

    selectedRows.Select '<------ fail here
    Copy Worksheets("main").Range("A3")
End Sub
```

The macro failed and error message said: Select method or Range class failed.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should test if `selectedRows = Nothing` before Selecting. Also, is `Worksheets("contacts")` hidden by any chance? One more thought try starting with `Set selectedRows = Worksheets("contacts").Range("A1")` as you test `B1` in your loop and not sure if you can have it in your selected range twice.

Comment: Without too much testing the code worked for me - except that last line which should be `Worksheets("main").Range("A3").Copy`.  **Edit:** But I did have the correct sheet selected - the code given by @PawelCzyz should work.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error msg because sheet "contacts" is not active. Add this line:

```
Worksheets("contacts").Activate
```

Like this:

```
Sub filter()
    'Clear prev result table
    Worksheets("main").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Delete

    'Declare variable
    Dim selectedRows As Range
    Set selectedRows = Worksheets("contacts").Range("A1:B1")


    'Get total used range in contacts database
    numRows = Mid(Worksheets("contacts").UsedRange.Address, 9)
    For Each cell In Worksheets("contacts").Range("B1:B" & numRows)
        If cell.Value = Worksheets("main").Range("B1").Value Then
            'If true, push into array called selectedRows
            Set selectedRows = Application.Union(selectedRows, Worksheets("contacts").Range(cell.Address))
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets("contacts").Activate

    selectedRows.Select '<------ fail here

    'this line below is incorrect
    'Copy Worksheets("main").Range("A3")
End Sub
```

I recommend reading this post: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) - it will help you improve your code.

Comment: still not succesful

Comment: `Copy Worksheets("main").Range("A3")` should be `Worksheets("main").Range("A3").Copy`

Comment: I have edited my answer - like Darren pointed - last line of your macro is incorrect - let me know what you wanted to get done with it. I might be able to correct it as well.

Comment: Should it be `selectedRows.Copy Worksheets("main").Range("A3")`?